# My comments on Stack Overflow get deleted

Tags: support, comments, deleted-comments

An hour ago I were helping a user to solve his question. He is an Android beginner and thus the comments we left were quite many. When his question was fixed and my answer got accepted, our comments were gone. Someone seems to have deleted our comments.

Comment: Hopefully you put the relevant information from the comments *into your answer*. If they didn't understand the answer as-written, it is likely that other beginners wouldn't either.

Comment: @CodyGray noted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your comments are no longer needed now that the problem has been resolved and the question answered. It's not a bad thing.

If someone were to remove your comments mid-conversation, though, that would be a bit rude, but it does indicate that things are dragging out a little too long and it might be worth moving over to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com) to continue your discussion. Comments on Q&A are not meant or suited for drawn-out conversations.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. We want to move to the chat for discussion but we can't create it

Comment: I agree on most  part of @BoltClock comment, except for one about "mid-conversation comments ". Could a topic starter delete comments, considering those as 'lack information' and etc?

Comment: @Reborn: No but a moderator could purge the comments mid-conversation. *Usually* this is done if the conversation is a heated argument, not a 1-to-1 tech support conversation, though...

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks for clearification, didn't knew that.